# Using a Windows Server on Google Cloud to host a shared license for a software

Tags: google-cloud-platform, windows-server-2012, license-key

Our company bought a shared license of a software so that all of our members can use the software (not at the same time). The shared license needs to be put in a Windows Server 64-bit.
I tried creating an image of Windows Server on Google Cloud Platform and installed the shared license in it. But I was unable to connect to the server from the software on client PC. Does it require any special configuration on Googlecloud-based Windows Server in order to host the license?

The shared license is based on NetKey License Server. Here's a quote from their website:
"NetKey License Server (NKLS) is a TCP/IP based service application that functions as a license server to allocate a pool of licenses to the application. NKLS supports a variety of network licensing, including floating concurrent licenses, roaming licenses, Terminal Server licenses, and ASP.NET sessions."

Please help! Thanks!

Tai

Comment: Are you able to RDP to the instance? Also please check the firewall rules [link](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls) that allow client PC connection to GCP instances.

Comment: The NetKey License Server default port is 1245. Did you create a VPC firewall rule allowing this port number?